# Supermartingale variance bound?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, martingales, variance

Suppose I have a supermartingale

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mid X_n,  \dots , X_2, X_1] \leq X_n
$$

There are 2 other conditions:

- bounded difference: $|X_{n+1} - X_n| \leq A$ with probability $1$ (almost surely) for all $n$, where $A$ is a constant
- all $X_n$ are lower bounded: $X_n \geq B$ with probability $1$ (almost surely) for all $n$, where $B$ is a constant

My question is, is there a way to bound the variance $\mathrm{Var}[X_n]$ for all $n$?

Ideally the bound on the variance $\mathrm{Var}[X_n]$ should $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $A \to 0$. So are there other (possibly known) conditions that are needed?

Comment: Should you not prescribe the variance of $X_1$?

Comment: At the moment, there's a trivial counterexample obtained by setting $X_{i+1} = X_i$ for all $i>1$. Then $A=0$ but as $n \to \infty$, $\text{Var}[X_n]$ stays at $\text{Var}[X_1]$, whatever that was.